# Relation or relative?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, **relation** and **relative** have the same meaning

> A person who is in the same family as somebody else.

I wonder if there are any differences between them. Is is up to me using them in any cases?[image: dictionary]

Comment: Related question that might be helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/95073/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the phrases "**any** **relation**" and "**no** **relation**", we [always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20he%20any%20relation%2Cis%20he%20any%20relative&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20he%20any%20relation%3B%2Cc0) use the word "relation".

> Is he any relation of yours?
>
> John Smith was friends with Brian Smith (no relation).

(We would not say "any relative".  It would, however, be correct to say "Is he **a relative** of yours?" or "not **a relative**" - though in the latter case, "no relation" is more idiomatic in most contexts.)

In a few expressions, such as "cared for **by relatives**", it is [virtually always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cared%20for%20by%20a%20relation%2Ccared%20for%20by%20a%20relative%2Ccared%20for%20by%20relations%2Ccared%20for%20by%20relatives&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccared%20for%20by%20a%20relative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccared%20for%20by%20relations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccared%20for%20by%20relatives%3B%2Cc0) "relatives".

Otherwise, the two are synonyms, but "relative" is the more common term.

In "relative by marriage", "close relative", "distant relative", "my relatives", etc, the term "relative" is significantly more common, but "relation" is equally correct.  It is also very much [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=closest%20relatives%2Cclosest%20relations%2Cdistant%20relatives%2Cdistant%20relations%2Cvisiting%20relatives%2Cvisiting%20relations&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclosest%20relatives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclosest%20relations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdistant%20relatives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdistant%20relations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvisiting%20relatives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvisiting%20relations%3B%2Cc0) to refer to "visiting relatives" than "visiting relations".

Of course, there are other (non-family-related) definitions of both words, so they differ in that respect, too.